# showing [object Object] displayed instead of the object properties

Tags: javascript, express, object, strapi

I'm using Strapi to create Api endpoints and consume those endpoints using expressjs. It's all for educational purposes.

Everything is working fine except displaying the object protperties in the browser. The endpoints is http://localhost:1337/restaurants
which display my data in json format:

```
[{"_id":"5cf19dd4a774126e9ca7f4fd","name":"Strapi Restaurant 1","description":"Strapi restaurant is a cosy restaurant delivering one of the very fastest and nicest dining experiences in the world, combining nods to tradition with fierce modernity, warmth with daring.\n# Strapi restaurant #\n- \n- \n1. \n2. \n3. ","createdAt":"2019-05-31T21:34:12.426Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-31T21:34:12.432Z","__v":0,"id":"5cf19dd4a774126e9ca7f4fd","categories":[{"restaurants":["5cf19dd4a774126e9ca7f4fd"],"_id":"5cf19e00a774126e9ca7f4fe","category":"Italian","createdAt":"2019-05-31T21:34:56.318Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-31T21:35:32.058Z","__v":0,"id":"5cf19e00a774126e9ca7f4fe"}]},{"_id":"5cf1af8ea774126e9ca7f500","name":"Strapi restaurant 2","description":"This is a restaurant that will serve you empty plates with no food. It is for your own good. You will loose weight quickly. Enjoy","createdAt":"2019-05-31T22:49:50.548Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-31T22:49:50.579Z","__v":0,"id":"5cf1af8ea774126e9ca7f500","categories":[{"restaurants":["5cf1af8ea774126e9ca7f500"],"_id":"5cf19e08a774126e9ca7f4ff","category":"Contemporary","createdAt":"2019-05-31T21:35:04.815Z","updatedAt":"2019-05-31T22:49:50.570Z","__v":0,"id":"5cf19e08a774126e9ca7f4ff"}]}]
```

My express route uses axios to access api and response is showing data logged correctly in my cmd

Now my route code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var axios = require("axios");

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
     axios.get('http://localhost:1337/restaurants')
       .then(response => ( res.render('index', { title: response.data}), console.log(response) ));
          });
    module.exports = router;
```

my PUG file is just trying to display the "reponse.data" using the variable "title":

```
extends layout
block content

  //  response from the strapiapp api
  //  p  restaurant name is : #{title}
  p  Restaurant name is: #{title.name}
```

Here is a screenshot of my cmd
[image]

It is the typical setup and I have done it so many times with different apis. My browser renders [object Object] if I use #{title}and if I use #{title.name} it will show nothing. But the data is logged correctly to my cmd.

How to display the object in my browser? title.name and titel.description are not working but the data is logged in my cmd express is logging the data object correctly.

Any idea why it is not displaying the object properties?

Comment: The data from the API looks to be an array of objects rather than just an object. You’d either need to extract out the first item of this array before you send it to the template or loop in the template.

Comment: can you post the output of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: @dimitristseggenes I posted an image of the console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as Alexander commented `response.data` is an array. So you can loop this array to display all data. I have not used pug before but i think this should work.

```
ul
  each val in title
    li= val.name
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Your pug code is correct. Thank you both for your help.